# How to retrieve data from a database based on two dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I've got the data retrieval working for one drop down selection using ajax but i want it to retrieve data based on two drop-down selection conditions. How do i parse two variables to my showChoice  function and then store the 2nd choice in another variable. I would appreciate any help.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function showChoice(str) {
        if (str == "") {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
          return;
        } else { 
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
          xmlhttp.send();
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <form>
      <select name="choices" onchange="showChoice(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select a departure point:</option>
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="New Castle">New Castle</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the getuser.php doc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    }

    th {text-align: left;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
      $q = $_GET["q"];


      $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','busdb');
      if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }

      mysqli_select_db($con,"busdb");
      $sql="SELECT * FROM busRoutes WHERE Departure = '".$q."'";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


      echo "<table>
      <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Departure</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th>Time</th>

      </tr>";
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Departure'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Destination'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";


      mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this , have a look. may be you need to include jquery library if you missed this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

update your code like this

```
function showChoice(str,sel2) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str+"&q2="+sel2,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.select').change(function()
    {
        var sel1=$('#select1').val();
        var sel2=$('#select2').val();
        showChoice(sel1,sel2);

    })

});
```

html will look like this

```
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select id="select1" class="select" name="choices">
<option value="">Select a departure point:</option>
<option value="London">London</option>
<option value="New Castle">New Castle</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" class="select" name="choices2">
<option value="">Select a departure point:</option>
<option value="London">London</option>
<option value="New Castle">New Castle</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kvvohev2/)

**update2**

getuser.php

```
<?
echo $q=$_GET['q'];
echo $q2=$_GET['q2'];

?>
```

Comment: i appreciate the help bud, i updated my sql select statement as follows:

    $sql="SELECT * FROM busRoutes WHERE Departure = '".$q."' AND     Destination = '".$q2."'";

but nothing seems to happen, no errors even.

Could you explain the code under the $(dcoument).ready(function() and why you added it?

Comment: did you add $q2 = $_GET["q2"]; in your php file??

Comment: $(dcoument).ready(function() is just a jquery event. here is full description http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Yeah i did.  It seems only the first dropdown responds to any mysql statements

Comment: check update in answer and your txtHint div . values are printing or not??

Comment: Londonundefined. Is the output when london is selected

Comment: did you added html for second select box ?? here it is working for both for me and also on this link http://jsfiddle.net/kvvohev2/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ohwx0zz9/

This is the exact code on my side, i did add the second select box. What could i be doing different to you

Comment: problem is in your php code . place only echo $q=$_GET['q'];
echo $q2=$_GET['q2']; in you php file and check.

Comment: or add  ini_set('display_errors', '1'); at the top of your getuser.php file

Comment: all i keep getting is the first selection and undefined for the second one

londonundefined

Comment: It worked when i input new records into my database, which doesnt really make sense to me but i'm not going to argue with it.

Thanks for being so patient with me while helping me out.